# React Native url deep linking like YouTube

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

My goal is to allow users share content from the application to external world (for example Viber, Whats App etc)

Here is the code:

```
import {Share} from 'react-native'

Share.share({ message:  'appscheme://feeds/:feedId'})
```

However this link is not **clickable** hence is useless since cannot open the app

What about `Share.share({ message:  'https://appscheme.com/feeds/:feedId'})`

My goal is to achieve the same behavior as YouTube video sharing. You can press on **video share**, send it to anybody in chat, and then to access it right from there.
For example:

[image]

Than you in advance!

Comment: do you want them to get a `link` that leads to your website/app?

Comment: I want to be able to share a clickable link which redirects to the react native app

Comment: can you share your linking config? You need to add prefixes to your linking so the device will be able to redirect to your app if one of the prefixes detected.

Answer (score 1):

That is called [universal link(iOS)](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6080-universal-links-make-the-connection) / [App Links (Android)](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links)

FYR: https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#open-links-and-deep-links-universal-links

Getting the link opening your app:

```
function handleURL(url) {
    // your stuff
}

useEffect(() => {
    function addLinkingEventListener() {
        Linking.addEventListener('url', evt => {
            handleURL(evt?.url)
        })
    }

    Linking.getInitialURL()
        .then(initUrl => {
            handleURL
        })
        .catch(handleError)
        .finally(() => {
            addLinkingEventListener()
        })

    return () => {
        Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleUrlEvent)
    }
}, [])
```