# React Native deep linking is not working on real device

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I use [uri-scheme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uri-scheme) for environment setup and testing and follow the steps from [React Navigation Doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking) to set up navigation. When I test on the emulator by `npx uri-scheme open myapp://do_something/some_params --{android/ios}` everything looks good. It works when the app is running foreground, background, or closed. However, when I try on my phone, nothing happens.

I try clicking the link in the email, nothing happens.
In the browser address bar, I try typing the uri `myapp://do_something/some_params`. The browser is still on the homepage, and no 'open myapp' popup.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
```

Info.plist:

```
...
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>myapp</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
...
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}
...
```

App.js:

```
const deepLinkingConfig = {
  prefixes: ['myapp://'],
  config: {
    screens: {
      HOME: {
        screens: {
          SOMESCREEN: 'do_something/:some_params',
        }
      }
    },
  },
}
...
<NavigationContainer linking={deepLinkingConfig}>
    ...
<NavigationContainer />
...
```

I can't find anything wrong.

Comment: For me, it was related to HTTP call bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won’t be clickable until you provide a real http schema for your app

You must configure universal links, see here: [React Native url deep linking like YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70021791/react-native-url-deep-linking-like-youtube)

iOS: https://www.raywenderlich.com/6080-universal-links-make-the-connection

Android: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Also take a look at Firebase Dynamic Links: https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI7Nixubba9AIVxrLVCh0m4wFnEAAYASAAEgI0nfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Do I have to use universal linking instead of uri scheme? I think uri scheme has better device support. Also universal linking only available for IOS

Comment: Yes it will be good to make universal linking. Here you will find more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70021791/react-native-url-deep-linking-like-youtube

Comment: This link above is my question. I followed the needed steps and my universal linking is working perfectly. Only one thing I dont understand is why there is so little information about react native linking

Answer (score 0):

You should create a small sample HTML page that contains the link and open this page in your Browser. If you enter the link into the browser deeplinking is not called, only by clicking the link. Also not all apps (like maybe your mail client) support deep linking. Furthermore you should first start your app with the configuration and then give the system a little bit time (up to a minute) to register the change. If nothing works try uninstall and re-install. Deeplinking unfortunately has some weaknesses.

Comment: I am using gmail and gmail supports deep linking. When I change the link to an http address it works properly. It looks like the uri scheme is not registered in the OS so it doesn't recognize.